# Propagate wxMouseEvent to base class in wxWidget

Tags: c++, event-handling, wxwidgets

I have a derived class in which I want to skip mouse wheel events depending on a `bool` parameter. So in case I set `bScroll = true`, I want the base class Bar to handle the Scrollwheel Events. If `bScroll = false` i want them to be ignored.
With the code below the events never reach the base class's `OnMouseWheel` function. Is this some kind of propagation issue? 
How can I fix this?
Thanks!

```
class Foo : public Bar
{
 public: 
 Foo(wxWindow *pParent, bool bScroll = true) : Bar(pParent)
 { 
  m_scroll = bScroll;
 }
 bool m_scroll;
 protected:

 virtual void OnMouseWheel(wxMouseEvent& roEvent)
 {
  if(m_scroll)
   roEvent.Skip();
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is not to use virtual functions, but the opposite, to use non-virtual functions and correctly `Connect()` or `Bind()` both `Foo::OnMouseWheel()` and `Bar::OnMouseWheel()`.
And then doing `if(m_scroll) roEvent.Skip();` will be enough.
See [Event Handlers vs Virtual Methods](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_virtual)

Answer (score 0):

if(m_scroll) roEvent.Skip();
else Bar::OnMouseWheel(roEvent);

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I'd say its Just `if(m_scroll) Bar::OnMouseWheel(roEvent);`

Comment: This answer is wrong, there is no need to call the base class function explicitly and, in fact, it doesn't make any sense to call it if you do *not* skip this event handler because it will be called if you *do* skip it. @I.I. is very confused.